# How to configure i3 on Kubuntu 20.10

Tags: apt, kubuntu, kde, window-manager, i3-wm

I'm new (and a newbie) to the window managers world. I have Kubuntu 20.10 installed, and I'd like to understand how to setup, use and control i3 wm, with kde and Polybar.
I tried following a guide into the GitHub issues section, but it didn't work for me.
I installed i3-gaps-deb [following this](https://www.ryanlue.com/posts/2019-06-13-kde-i3) and added

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main universe
```

to `/etc/apt/source.list`
But if i ran `apt update` terminal shows errors:

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Hit:3 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease              
Hit:4 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease            
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease [108 kB]      
Get:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]             
Err:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                      
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Hit:7 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

So I'm wondering where to find further informations.
I'd like to make a working-setup similar to this: [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E05HgehixqM).
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing repositories is not a good idea, but you can proceed if you want to.  Moreover the *zesty* Ubuntu version is now end-of-life, so you can not use `archive.ubuntu.com` URLs for it, you should use `old-releases.ubuntu.com` for it.

To remove NO_PUBKEY messages use commands below:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5 
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
```

and then run `sudo apt-get update`.

Also note that official search engine for packages is located at https://packages.ubuntu.com and not on third-party blogs which are out-of-date.
If error persists after following the above method, then, please edit your question to specify your final idea.